# Querying inside range

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

Let's say I have the following columns

```
InsertedTime DateTime not null
ItemType tinyint not null

ItemType in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... , 255}
```

I have a query when it would run the fastest if indexed by `InsertedTime`: `where InsertedTime > Monday and InsertedTime < Tuesday`

However, I also want a query by ItemType within DateRange, let's say all rows with `ItemType == 0 and InsertedTime > Monday and InsertedTime < Tuesday`.

For the first query, it makes sense for the index to be `{InsertedTime, ItemType}`. However, if I use this index for the second query, sql would need to scan the entire date range result.

To optimize for the second query, I would use `{ItemType, InsertedTime}` index. But with this index, sql would need 256 seeks for the first query.

Is there a way to optimize for both queries using a single index?

Comment: What do you mean it would do 256 scans? And of course if you are really using an in all 256 valid numbers for a tinyint wouldn't  it make more sense to say ItemType is not null?

Comment: You wouldn’t actually get a plan with 256 seeks for the second index and the first query, you would just get a scan unless you wrote the query cross applying onto the 256 values from a numbers table or similar. Unlikely to be worth doing unless the time part was highly selective.

Comment: Except if the table was partitioned on itemtype. But that is not a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue if you want to filter efficiently by "Monday" or "Tuesday" as those are only accessible by `datename(weekday,InsertedTime)` and you cannot use that as a persisted computed column as it is "non-deterministic" as it depends of such things as language settings, and even `datepart(weekday,InsertedTime)` suffers this as it is dependent on `firstday` setting.

To get a reliable integer representation of weekday (0 = Monday) that can be persisted try:

```
alter table Table1
add InsertedWeekday as (datediff(day,0,InsertedTime)%7) persisted;
```

You could probably also create a case expression from that same logic to get the day name labels if really needed.

The persusted computed column could then be included in indexes e.g.

```
create index ixWeekdayType on Table1 (InsertedWeekday,ItemType);
```

Which may assist this style of query:

```
select *
from Table1
where InsertedWeekday in (0,1) -- Monday/Tuesday
and ItemType between 20 and 30
```

---

NOT that I am recommending it, but the following is "deterministic" and hence allowed:

```
alter table Table1
add InsertedWeekdayName as (case datediff(day,0,InsertedTime)%7
                     when 0 then 'Monday'
                     when 1 then 'Tuesday'
                     when 2 then 'Wednesday'
                     when 3 then 'Thursday'
                     when 4 then 'Friday'
                     when 5 then 'Saturday'
                     when 6 then 'Sunday'
                        end
                     ) persisted;
```